# Change a comment's body programatically

Tags: comments, forms

I am building a small custom module that will change the value of a comment's body when the comment in posted. So far I have:

```
function comment_loader_comment_insert($comment) {
}
```

So pretty much nothing, just that I want to use hook_comment_insert to change after the comment has been posted.

So what do I need to affect the comment body?

[I am a student who is just learning php and drupal, so clarity is appreciated]

**edit:**

code so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function comment_loader_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'comment_loader_comment_form_validate';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_validate().
 */
function comment_loader_comment_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_body = 'some text';
  $form_state['values']['comment_body']['#object']->comment_body['und'[0]['value'] = $new_body;
}
```

Still doesn't have any affect. I am no working in a development environment so I don't know if there are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_comment_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7) is fired after the comment body has already been saved to the database, so it's probably not the hook you're looking for.

Instead you could hook up your own validation function to the comment form and alter the body there. That way you're not having to make any extra db calls.

In it's simplest terms you would implement [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and add the validation function like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_comment_form_validate';
}

function MYMODULE_comment_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $current_body = $form_state['values']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

  $new_body = $current_body . ' some extra text';

  $form_state['values']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $new_body;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Do I need to change the '$form_state[][]' stuff to match what I can see in devel?

Comment: I'd try it with the above code to start with (out of the box that's what the comment form should look like, but it's very possible a custom/contrib module has altered it). If that doesn't work then yeah, delve into devel and change it to match

Comment: And shouldn't I be using 'hook_form_submit()' not validate (I really have no idea)?

Comment: It might be too late to alter the body in the submit handler; if the comment module's submit handler runs first the comment will already be committed to the database and you'll have missed your chance to change it (this time round at least). The validate handle is usually the best place to do this sort of thing.

Comment: So that's what I got above. No effect with either your code or mine. Anything I did wrong in mine?

Comment: You don't want to be adding to the `#object` as that won't be processed...I tried this code before I posted it and it worked on a plain drupal site. Did you clear you Drupal's cache after writing the form alter hook? Hook implementations get cached in Drupal 7

Comment: Hmm. So took out the '#object' and noticed the '[und[', it still didn't work so took out '->comment_body', still no, went back to your original, still no. I did't know about clearing cache, but did it between every upload of the file this time.

Comment: Not really sure what to say I'm afraid, the code works perfectly so I'm guessing you have another module/theme interfering and causing problems :/